# How to Fix Syntax error in Wordpress Blog for a theme

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, syntax-error

I am new to programming and while trying to remove a footer message from the site, some coding went wrong and I am getting this error message in my site.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in G:\Inetpub\vhosts\socialwebarena.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\spacious\inc\functions.php on line 440


/**************************************************************************************/

add_action( 'spacious_footer_copyright', 'spacious_footer_copyright', 10 );
/**
 * function to show the footer info, copyright information
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'spacious_footer_copyright' ) ) :
function spacious_footer_copyright() {
    $site_link = '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ) . '" ><span>' . get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) . '</span></a>';

    //$wp_link = '<a href="'.esc_url( 'http://wordpress.org' ).'" target="_blank" title="' . esc_attr__( 'WordPress', 'spacious' ) . '"><span>' . __( 'WordPress', 'spacious' ) . '</span></a>';

    //$tg_link =  '<a href="'.esc_url( 'http://themegrill.com/themes/spacious' ).'" target="_blank" title="'.esc_attr__( 'ThemeGrill', 'spacious' ).'" rel="designer"><span>'.__( 'ThemeGrill', 'spacious') .'</span></a>';

    //$default_footer_value = sprintf( __( 'Copyright &copy; %1$s %2$s.', 'spacious' ), date( 'Y' ), $site_link ).' '.sprintf( __( 'Powered by %s.', 'spacious' ), $wp_link ).' '.sprintf( __( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s.', 'spacious' ), 'Spacious', $tg_link );

$default_footer_value = sprintf( __( 'Copyright &copy; %1$s %2$s.', 'spacious' ), date( 'Y' ), $site_link ).' '.sprintf( __( 'Powered by %s.', 'spacious' ), $wp_link ).', $tg_link );

    $spacious_footer_copyright = '<div class="copyright">'.$default_footer_value.'</div>';
    echo $spacious_footer_copyright;
}
endif;

/*
```

This is the section and the closing braces just before endif; is line no 440. Can anyone help me to fix this. I asked the host service, but they mentioned that something has gone wrong in the coding.

Can someone help me in this

Comment: your `add_action` looks incorret. You are using the same function for the hook and callback.

Comment: @Anand that is allowed, action hook and function name can be identical

Comment: @diggy, thank you. learned something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Your add action is incorrect, Please check below sample for use of add_action in word-press.You need to apply hook name in first argument instead of your custom function.

```
<?php add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args ); ?>
```

**$hook** (string) (required)

The name of the action to which $function_to_add is hooked. (See Plugin API/Action Reference for a list of action hooks). Can also be the name of an action inside a theme or plugin file, or the special tag "all", in which case the function will be called for all hooks.

**$function_to_add** (callback) (required)

The name of the function you wish to be hooked.

Default: None

**$priority** (int) (optional)

Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.

**$accepted_args** (int) (optional)

The number of arguments the hooked function accepts. In WordPress 1.5.1+, hooked functions can take extra arguments that are set when the matching do_action() or apply_filters() call is run. For example, the action comment_id_not_found will pass any functions that hook onto it the ID of the requested comment.

Default: 1

For more info. about **add_action** you can visit [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
sprintf( __( 'Powered by %s.', 'spacious' ), $wp_link ).', $tg_link );
```

to

```
sprintf( __( 'Powered by %s.', 'spacious' ), $wp_link );
```